# Weird Mesh artifacts

Tags: mesh

[image]

I've Knife Projected a shape onto my object which I want to extrude inwards, however once the shape is projected on the mesh shows dark spots and clear deformation in wire frame mode, I tried Alt+F fill but that only intensified the dark spots.
Removing doubles had no effect either.

Comment: Those look like z-fighting artifacts. I would suppose there may another surface nearly coincident with that visible surface that is slightly coming through from below. Deselect all with A once or twice. Then manually select the visible faces in that area one at a time. Then hit Alt+I to invert the selection, then hit H to hide all those other faces. If the black areas disappear, that is likely your problem.

Comment: Knife projection is a "lazy way of modeling" and produces bad topology by default. It requires cleanup afterwards, and is unsuited for direct use with *Sbdivision Surface* modifiers afterwards.

Comment: This can be caused by bad topology and distorted n-gons

Comment: Even when I tried applying the shape manually with the knife tool I'm still getting dark areas.